# How would I sort all the values of an array of hashes in Rails? Mongo

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, hash

I have a controller action that grabs some information for me:

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
@acct_cust = Customer.all(:account_id => @account.id.to_s)
@acct_cust.each do |ac|
  @jobAc << Job.where(:customer_id => ac.id).sort(:start_date)
end
```

We have the account, then we grab all the customers who belong to this account, then we grab all the jobs of each customer and shove them into an array.

**So what I want to do is sort that final array - @jobAc - by the :start_date value.**

Of course I start with plucky queries shoved into this array as you see in the log:

Console log:

```
 jobAc is [#<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery customer_id:  
 BSON::ObjectId('52705ff24031a0000e000179'), sort: [["start_date", 1]], transformer:  
 #<Proc:0x007fe3e6f834d8@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0.beta2
 /lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>, 
 #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery customer_id: 
 BSON::ObjectId('5279795e2f6984000b00014f'), sort: [["start_date", 1]], transformer: 
 #<Proc:0x007fe3eb13b8f8@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0.beta2
 /lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>, 
 #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery customer_id: 
 BSON::ObjectId('52797beb2f698400ef0000c4'), sort: [["start_date", 1]], transformer: 
 #<Proc:0x007fe3e9da35e8@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0.beta2
 /lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>, 
 #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery customer_id: 
 BSON::ObjectId('527dac2d3d126f0107000059'), sort: [["start_date", 1]], transformer: 
 #<Proc:0x007fe3eb170cb0@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0.beta2
 /lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>]
```

If I use `@jobAc = Job.all(query)` I end up with an array of the values like this:

```
[[{1},{2},{3}],[{1},{2}]]
```

I can't even understand the question I'm trying to ask properly :)  Am I trying to flatten an array of hashes?  I tried that but didn't come up with what I thought.

I tried :

`@jobAc.sort_by!(&:start_date).reverse but this of course cannot be done while they are plucky queries instead of the actual values.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're selecting only parts of your dataset at a time in a loop, rather than sorting the whole dataset.

You can improve the runtime of this code and apply the sort by performing a single query to find all your jobs, with a sort parameter:

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
@acct_cust = Customer.all(:account_id => @account.id.to_s)
@jobAc = Job.where(:customer_id.in => @acct_cust.map(:id)).sort(:start_date)
```

Since you're using MongoMapper, I'd recommend that you use associations and scopes:

```
class Account
  many :customers
end

class Customer
  belongs_to :account
end

class Job
  scope :for_account, ->(account) do
    where(:customer_id.in => account.customers.fields(:id).all.map(:id))
  end
end
```

Then you can just find all the jobs for a given customer:

```
@jobAc = Job.for_account( Account.find(params[:id]) )
```

Comment: Hi Chris - I know who you are - thanks for all your hard work!  And thanks for answering this question.  The query you've written works at the top (and is just beyond my understanding at this point in time), but the scope you wrote below is throwing an error.  The syntax needed to be changed to .map(&:id) but even then I'm getting "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" on page load.  I'm using the mongo_mapper 0.13.0.beta2 gem - perhaps it's a bug.  THANK YOU for the help

Comment: Sorry, the `map(:id)` is Ruby 2.0 only. What's the stack trace on the exception look like?

Comment: The only way it would work is with the & syntax like this: scope :for_account, ->(account) do
    where(:customer_id.in => account.customers.fields(:id).all.map(&:id)).sort(:start_date.desc)
  end    But now it works great!